# How to clear content from excel file using batch script?

Tags: batch-file

How to clear content from excel file using batch script?

i tried this , but it doesnot work

```
type nul > test.xlsx
```

Answer (score 0):

excel files are not text ones and even empty ones contains some binary metadata.
Try this (on the second line you can set the name of the new file):

```
@echo off
set newFile=new.xslx

certutil -f -decode "%~f0" "%newFile%"

exit /b %errorlevel%


-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: i get this error while running above code.                                     DecodeFile returned The data is invalid. 0x8007000d (WIN32: 13)
CertUtil: -decode command FAILED: 0x8007000d (WIN32: 13)
CertUtil: The data is invalid.
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: @AVK - are you sure you copied the whole script

Comment: @AVK - you need the last line.Otherwise the certutil will not know until when to read the file.

Comment: I tried with whole code, still excel contents not getting cleared.

Comment: @AVK - have you changed the name of the excel file? At the moment it's `new.xslx` and should clear\create file with such name.

Answer (score 0):

```
copy nul test.xlsx
```

should replace the file with a zero-length file, effectively deleting the data.

Answer (score 0):

Check following folders ([might vary depending on your OS and Excel version](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-how-Excel-starts-6509b9af-2cc8-4fb6-9ef5-cf5f1d292c19)):

- `C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows\Templates`
- `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Templates`
- `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART`
- `%useprofile%\Templates`

There could be an Excel template e.g.  (otherwise, [create i](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-a-workbook-or-worksheet-as-a-template-58c6625a-2c0b-4446-9689-ad8baec39e1e)t)

- `Book.xlt` (`.xltx` / `.xltm`) or
- `Sheet.xlt` (`.xltx` / `.xltm`).

Let us suppose that there is such a file `%useprofile%\Templates\Sheet.xltx`

Then next command should do the trick:

```
copy /Y /B "%useprofile%\Templates\Sheet.xltx" test.xlsx
```